# Evaluation Of Logarithmic Limits

Tags: limits

To Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\log(1+x)$$ why it's not allowed to replace $x$ by $0$ as we do in the case of polynomial functions?

Comment: $\log(1+x)$ is continuous, it's perfectly valid to 'evaluate' the limit by substituting $0$ for $x$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can replace because $\ln$ is a continuous function, which gives:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\ln(1+x)=\ln\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)\right)=\ln(1+0)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If a function (at least any elementary function, not only polynomials) is continuous at a particular point, the limit of the function at that point is equal to the functional value at that point:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0).$$

$f(x)=\log{(1+x)}$ is continuous at $x=0$. Therefore, direct substitution would work:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\log(1+x)=\log{(1+0)}=\log{(1)}=0.$$

Who says it's not allowed in this case? Where did you learn that?